# Stop VS2008 Unit Tests from creating loads of files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, mstest

After years of faithful nUnit use, I'm having a fling with the Visual Studio Unit Testing framework thats built into VS2008.

Apart from the crushing guilt ; ) ... one of the issues is that 'VSTest' creates a file and a folder every time you run tests, and those files ('Visual Studio Test Results File') and folders really build up over time.

Is there an easy way to make it clean up after itself, or a way of preventing it from making those files in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to prevent the Unit Test framework in Visual Studio from doing this.  However it should not build up uncontrolled.  After 25 test runs it will prompt you to delete previous run data before creating a new one thus keeping it at a steady state of 25 directories and associated files.

Are you not seeing that behavior?

Comment: Ah! I havent got to 25 yet. Thats not so bad then.

Comment: You can change the maximum number of test results VS keeps around too. In the Options, under Test Tools > Test Execution you can adjust the maximum.